# How do I retrieve the ID of a bitmap button in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

```
self.btid = 0
self.btarray = [] 
self.btarray.append("x")#so that the buttons are appended according to their ids


self.bmt = wx.BitmapButton(panel, btid, pic, pos=(50,50))
self.btarray.append(self.bmt)

self.btid += 1
```

I create multiple buttons using the same code. How do I retrieve an individual buttons' ID later on?

Thanks in advance,
Swayam

Comment: you are not setting any id to the button. you are not defining btid but self.btid

Comment: I am iteratively creating multiple buttons, and the value of btid is being incremented by 1 after each iteration

Comment: No, `btid` is not being incremented in your code. `self.btid` is.

Comment: joaquin, that was my mistake, its self.bitd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetId` is the method to get the Id of an object. 
So you can write:

```
id_of_button_n = button_n.GetId()
```

**However** in your case, this is not neccessary because you already stored the ids as the keys of the dictionary `self.btarray` !

Comment: I think I will use GetId(). That way I hope to not use the array!

Comment: Either you make `self.btarray` a dictionary or you pre-fill the list `self.btarray`. Otherwise your code will not work. You can not assign to an empty list like you did. With an empty list the way to go is to `append`

Comment: Thanks! Even If I have an array of buttons, how do I get the id of an individual element just by clicking on the button in the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty script that will show you how to get button ids and labels. I'm using normal wx.Button objects since there's no good way to include images for bitmap buttons on Stack:

```
import random
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        i = random.choice(range(5, 10))
        for index, item in enumerate(range(i)):
            num = index + 1
            btn = wx.Button(self, label="Button %s" % num)
            btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClick)
            mainSizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)

        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onClick(self, event):
        """"""
        btn = event.GetEventObject()
        print "%s id => %s" % (btn.GetLabel(), btn.GetId())

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Random Buttons", size=(1024, 768))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```